# Most efficient way to Add 2or more array of decimal/hex/binary

Tags: arrays, dart

Let say I have a string "compute" in dart,

String = "computer";

And it has some binary/hex/decimal value representation in array

Binary = [01100011 01101111 01101101 01110000 01110101 01110100 01100101 01110010]

Hex = [63 6F 6D 70 75 74 65 72]

Decimal = [99 111 109 112 117 116 101 114]

What is the best way to get a sum of the every 4 bytes (Dword) programatically?

**array of binary calculation**

```
  01100011 01101111 01101101 01110000

+ 01110101 01110100 01100101 01110010

(          sum here                  )
```

and if the string grows for example "this is computer", it will still will have to get the sum of every 4 bytes

ASCII - this is computer

HEX - 74 68 69 73 20 69 73 20 63 6F 6D 70 75 74 65 72

binary - 01110100 01101000 01101001 01110011 00100000 01101001 01110011 00100000 01100011 01101111
01101101 01110000 01110101 01110100 01100101 01110010

decimal - 116 104 105 115 32 105 115 32 99 111 109 112 117 116 101 114

**array of binary calculation**

```
  01110100 01101000 01101001 01110011

  00100000 01101001 01110011 00100000

  01100011 01101111 01101101 01110000

+ 01110101 01110100 01100101 01110010

(          sum here                  )
```

Comment: Could you give an example of what the expected sum should be in your examples? Is the sum restricted to also 4 bytes? If that is the case, I guess we are allowed to overflow?

Comment: yes the sum is restricted to also 4 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

If we assume that the input is 8-bit letters (e.g., ASCII only), then I'd do:

```dart
import "dart:typed_data";
int sumOfFourChars(String input) {
  var bytes = Uint8List((input.length + 3) & ~3); // round up to multiple of 4.
  bytes.setRange(0, input.length, input.codeUnits);
  var words = bytes.buffer.asUint32List();
  return words.fold<int>(0, (a, b) => a + b) & 0xFFFFFFFF; // If you want to drop overflows.
}
```

That's optimized for readability and brevity. If going for performance, I'd probably compute the sum locally:

```dart
  var result = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) result += words[i];
  return result;
```

This sum uses the platform endianness (usually little endian on intel chips). If you need the result to be the same on different platforms, you may want to use `ByteData` instead, so you can control the endianness:

```dart
  var words = bytes.buffer.asByteData();
  var result = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < words.lengthInBytes; i += 4) {
    result += words.getUint32(i, Endian.little);
  }
  return result;
```

These approaches all depend on copying bytes into a typed-data list first.
To avoid that, you can do that yourself.

```dart
int sumOfFourChars(String input) {
  var result = 0;
  var i = 0;
  while (i + 4 <= input.length) {
    result += input.codeUnitAt(i);
    result += input.codeUnitAt(i + 1) << 8;
    result += input.codeUnitAt(i + 2) << 16;
    result += input.codeUnitAt(i + 3) << 24;
    i += 4;
  }
  if (i < input.length) {
    result += input.codeUnitAt(i);
    if (i + 1 < input.length) {
      result += input.codeUnitAt(i + 1) << 8;
      if (i + 2 < input.length) {
        result += input.codeUnitAt(i + 2) << 16;
      }
    }
  }
  return result & 0xFFFFFFFF;
}
```

This still assumes that all characters are bytes (otherwise you might want to convert to UTF-8).

An alternative which relies on computed shifts (something intel CPUs are traditionally a little slower at) would be:

```dart
int sumOfFourChars(String input) {
  var result = 0;
  var shift = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    result = result + (input.codeUnitAt(i) << shift) & 0xFFFFFFFF;
    shift = (shift + 8) & 0x1f;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Actual performance needs to be measured for realistic data and the target platform. I'd probably go with the last one myself, because brevity of code is an advantage in itself, and only do something more complicated after measurements have shown the code to be a bottleneck in practice.

---

If the desired result is a four-byte array where each byte is added independently (not overflowing into the next byte), the simplest approach would be:

```dart
Uint8List addFourBytes(Uint8List input) {
  var result = Uint8List(4);
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) result[i & 3] += input[i];
  return result;
}
```

It might be possible to be faster than this using SIMD operations, but Dart doesn't provide any `Uint8x16` type, like it does `Int32x4`, so it's not something there is direct support for,

Comment: Hi!
Thanks for the reply,

is there a way for us to check the performance of between the two in flutter for execution time?

Comment: I wouldn't bother with a minor performance improvement unless I have measured that the code is dominating the rest of the application. It's unlikely to be measurable unless you do it a *lot* or on very large strings - and in the latter case, I'd do something completely different to avoid copying the bytes.

Comment: thanks for your help
btw for the 1st one, it will throw out an error
 return words.fold(0, (a, b) => a + b) & 0xFFFFFFFF;


 "message": "The operator '+' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.\nTry adding a null check to the target ('!').",

Comment: Good catch, added an explicit `<int>` to help the type inference.

Comment: and after getting the result, what's the proper way to convert it back to byte array? i tried .codeUnit and asInt32List, might not be the proper way as both doesnt turn out to show the 4 bytes in list that i want

Comment: Since you said DWord, I assumed you wanted a 32-bit result (and sum). I'll write another answer if you actually want a four-byte array result without carry between the individual bytes.

Comment: there's a few other process involved after getting the sum, actually, like inversed bitwise, and few other things, 

ok, lets just assume after getting the result of sum, i want the result in byte array.

Comment: very thorough answer, please update here if you found a way to test the performance.